# Math italics with unicode-math.

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontspec, unicode

I'm using Tex Live 2010. Here's the example I want to discuss.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\RequirePackage{amsmath}  
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}  
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}   
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}  
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}]{Linux Libertine O}  
\begin{document}  
Transfinite induction will reveal that $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Mahlo for each
$\alpha < \kappa$. We have proved elsewhere that $\kappa$ is 1-Mahlo, and hence
0-Mahlo. If $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Mahlo for all $\alpha$ below some limit ordinal
$\lambda < \kappa$, then $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-Mahlo by definition.  
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the latin, Latin, greek, and Greek characters are set in XITS, not Libertine. Now fontspec issues the warning,

> fontspec Warning: Font 'Linux Libertine O' does not contain script 'Math'.

I guess Libertine isn't a math font. Nevertheless, similar markup seemed to yield the desired result in June at [this blog](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/the-unicode-math-package-for-xelatex-and-the-stix-fonts/). Has something changed dramatically since then?

I'm unwilling to abandon unicode-math. But I desperately want to use, within math mode, Latin and Greek glyphs that were designed for text mode. Since (as far as I know) mathspec is no longer compatible with unicode-math, I'm not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: This behaviour has now been reported as a bug: http://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues#issue/157

Comment: @WillRobertson An old question, but would you mind adding an answer?

Comment: As the bug was fixed, the question can be closed (no future answers needed or meaningful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, the question has already been answered on [xetex mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-October/018741.html).

Comment: There's also an answer in the comments section of the blog linked to.

Comment: Could you please copy the main part in you answer. This site should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

When this question was written, there was a bug in the option code that caused the spaces in `{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}` to upset the parsing (it was looking for a range called `Latin` with a leading space).

This bug was corrected shortly afterwards and the example given should now behave correctly. (Although one wonders if the original poster intended to use an italic font instead for `\mathit`.)